# ¿Cómo eliminar nodo de lista enlazada con punteros shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, punteros, punteros-inteligentes

Tengo una clase `Cola` que internamente maneja una lista enlazada simple, pero la cuestión es que antes la tenía implementada con punteros crudos y podía insertar y eliminar nodos sin problema, pero al cambiar los punteros a `shared_ptr` no me deja hacer delete para eliminar nodos de la lista.

```
class Cola{
    struct Nodo{
        int dato;
        std::shared_ptr<Nodo> sig;
        Nodo(int dato_):dato{dato_},sig{}{}
    };
    std::shared_ptr<Nodo> primero;
    std::shared_ptr<Nodo> ultimo;
public:
    Cola();
    void push(int dato);
    int front() const;
    void pop();
    bool empty() const;
};
```

Este es el método en donde mi IDE me salta el error al intentar eliminar el nodo.

```
void Cola::pop(){
    //Si la cola esta vacia no hace nada
    if(primero == nullptr) return;

    if(primero == ultimo){
        //Si la cola tiene un solo elemento, lo elimina y vuelve a nulo la lista
        delete primero; //--> cannot delete expression of type std::shared_ptr<Nodo>
        primero = ultimo = nullptr;
    }else{
        //Si no es ninguno de los dos casos anteriores elimina el primer elemento
        std::shared_ptr<Nodo> aux = primero;
        primero = primero->sig;
        delete aux; //--> cannot delete expression of type std::shared_ptr<Nodo>
    }
}
```

La definición del resto de los métodos no los publico porque el IDE no me muestra ningún error en ellos, solo en el método `pop` el cual elimina el primer elemento de la lista.

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando punteros inteligentes.

En el momento en que no haya más referencias a `shared_ptr`, la memoria será liberada automáticamente. No necesitas llamar a `delete` explícitamente.

`unique_ptr` funciona de la misma manera pero es más simple. Ya que solo puede existir una referencia.

Más información [aquí](https://cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/).